# Resource.xaml in Avalonia

Tags: xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am creating an app using avalonia which has some UI stuff in another assembly because of re-usability. Within this additional assembly, i want to have a Resource.xml file which is referenced by the application project and other projects. It contains styles etc.

Content:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >
    <Style x:Key="normal_button" Selector="Button.normal_button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Error:

```
Unable to find suitable setter or adder for property Content of type Avalonia.Styling:Avalonia.Controls.ResourceDictionary for argument Avalonia.Styling:Avalonia.Styling.Style, available setter parameter lists are: ...
```

What am i doing wrong? Are there some entries in the .csproj file necessary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Avalonia styles can't be used from resource dictionaries. You need `Styles` as a root of your shared file and `StyleInclude` for inclusion.

e. g.
https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/samples/ControlCatalog/SideBar.xaml

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/samples/ControlCatalog/App.xaml#L18